# Female Zen teachers and writers

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, zen, gender

The Zen center where I live is very male dominated. This might be because it's very small. Anyway, I think Zen sometimes tend to be a bit masculine in its form, wit a kind of quasi militaristic approach. I find this kind of fun and try to have an ironic attitude - irony is indeed a good medicine.

There are plenty of famous women in different schools of Buddhism, esecially Tibetan. But not so much in Zen, it seems.

Is there anyone who knows a good book on Zen practice written by a woman? And I'd also like some online resources/courses/training on Zen by women.

Answer (score 5):

Charlotte Joko Beck revolutionized how Zen - if not the whole of Buddhism - is taught in America.  Her books are extraordinary.  She also started the San Diego Zen Center.  Peggy Jiyu Kennett started Shasta Abbey.  Those are two that I know off the top of my head.

And a [link](http://lhamo.tripod.com/2zen.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Shundo Aoyama Roshi is a Sōtō priest who wrote a few books (I'm afraid just one was translated to english, however: [Zen Seeds: Reflections of a Female Priest](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Zen+Seeds%3A+Reflections+of+a+Female+Priest)). She is the teacher of Coen sensei, former head of the Sōtō community in south america.